# DataGrid Columns created in xaml - how to fill programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatable

I have created a DataGrid in xaml. Code is like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="305" Margin="36,157,-36,0" AutoGeneratingColumn="dgOverviewMain_AutoGeneratingColumn" Loaded="dgOverviewMain_Loaded" MouseUp="dgOverviewMain_MouseUp" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FFEDFDFF">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col1"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col2"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col3"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now I want to add rows programmatically with C#.

```
DataRow tempRow = dt_source.Rows[1];   //Get row from DataTable
myDataGrid.Items.Add(tempRow);         //Insert tempRow to myDataGrid
```

tempRow.ItemsArray is containing my data, but the line obove only generates blank rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is dt_source? Why aren't you binding to your datatable?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I tried:       myDataGrid .SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = dt_source })      ---> Only adds Rows if AutoGenerateColumns is enabled, BUT data is shown in new generated columns an not in my predefined columns (Col1, Col2, Col3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col1"/>` do not define what should be displayed in the contents. Therefore nothing is bound to each cell.

By having `Binding="{x:Null}"` you are specifically saying you want it to be blank.

Replace it with  `Binding="{Binding ColumnName}"`

Comment: What is "ColumnName"? Do you mean "Col1"?

Comment: How should I know what your columns are called!

Comment: hehe, got it now!   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UTC Time}"  ... />      solved my problem. ty!